# delete selected row from datagridview and datasource table

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i have a remove button like i would like to delete just sigle selected row from both datagridview and the acutual database.the problem I am having is in deleting selected row.if i dont use the parameter the contents of the table gets deleted ,i dont have any primery key just an ID field (AutoNumber).can someone help me with a sql statement please

i appreciate your help

```
enter code here
            Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        If Not DataGridView1.CurrentRow.IsNewRow Then
        If DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count = 0 Then
            MsgBox("No row was selected. If you are trying to remove a row, highlight the entire row by clicking on the identifier column            on the far left.", MessageBoxIcon.Error, "Entire Row Not Selected")

            ElseIf DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count = 1 Then
            Dim response As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete the selected row?", "Delete row?",                 MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2)
            If (response = DialogResult.Yes) Then
                DataGridView1.Rows.Remove(DataGridView1.CurrentRow)

                Dim cn As OleDbConnection
                Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
                Dim cnstring As String = ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\testdb1.accdb;Persist Security                     Info=False")
                Dim sqlstring As String = "Delete from sample where id = id"
                cn = New OleDbConnection(cnstring)
                cmd = New OleDbCommand(sqlstring, cn)
                cn.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                cn.Close()


                 End If
                  ElseIf DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 1 Then
                  MsgBox("Multiple rows are currently selected. The remove function can only delete one row at a time. Please select a                      single row and try again.", MessageBoxIcon.Error, "Single Row Not Selected")
                 DataGridView1.ClearSelection()
                 End If
                 End If

                End Sub
                End Class
enter code here
```

Answer (score 1):

While you are populating the data from the DB to datagridview, you can include the `ID` field too, but while showing data you can hide it. Then when you want to delete data you will have the `ID` in order to do that.

For example, suppose that we have as below:

```
sqlcommand command = new sqlcommand("SELECT IDHuman,HumanName,... FROM tblHuman",connection)
```

Now as you see, we have the ID as well and we should hide it as follows:

```
datagridview1.cells[0].visible=false;
```

Then when you want to delete it, you can include `ID` in your `WHERE` clause.