# Delete a row through DataGridView

Tags: vb.net

I have a `Button` that lists to me everything from a database and another `Button` that was made to delete something from database by "Name". To do that, I have a `TextBox` where I input the "Name" and delete it from the database.

To make things easy and faster I had another solution which is simpler than what I am currently doing. What I want it to do is click on a row and then press the delete `Button` and have the row be deleted from the database. I found this solution but this doesn't work:

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In myDataGrid.SelectedRows
    myDataGrid.Rows.Remove(row)
Next
```

Basically what I have to do in the code is make a query and select the row that I want right?

Answer (score 1):

The `For[...]Next` statement will only delete the `DataGridViewRow` from the `DataGridView`. It won't commit any changes to the database.

A `DataGridView` is a *view* of the data. You would need to commit the changes on the `DataSet`.

If you want a more specific answer post the code that shows how you are binding the data to the `DataGridView`.

Answer (score 1):

My apologies I am not able to comment. In either case, if you are trying to delete the record from the database, you will have to use a delete query.

Below is an example on how to do it:

[delete selected row from datagridview and datasource table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073951/delete-selected-row-from-datagridview-and-datasource-table?rq=1)

Without using a stored procedure you can use this code:

```
Dim cn As OleDbConnection
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
Dim cnstring As String = "Your connection String"
Dim sqlstring As String = "Delete from yourTable where column= your record"
cn = New OleDbConnection(cnstring)
cmd = New OleDbCommand(sqlstring, cn)
cn.Open()
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
cn.Close()
```